# Height of the status bar increased weirdly inside the android emulator (AVD)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

For some reason the height of the status bar in android emulator is increased. It's not limited to any app though. Attaching the screenshot below:

[image: AVD screenshot]

I have tried cold boot and all sorts of stuff. How can I fix this issue?

The last resort I think of is remove this emulator and create a new one. But my new emulator also starts facing this issue. I am not able to know the reason why this starts happening.

Comment: can you add some codes to your question for better understanding

Comment: did you manage to solve this? It's happening to me and I also have no clue why

Comment: No I haven't managed to solve this robustly yet. The only solution is to create a new emulator instance. But it reappears again after some time.

Comment: Dealing with the same issue, makes designing impossible on emulator

Comment: Any updates with this problem?

Comment: Looks like a Pixel 4 emulator problem. Try a Pixel 3 or 3a

Comment: Yes this happened to me using a Pixel 4 emulator

Comment: Same problem on Pixel 5

Answer (score 1):

Switching from the "Pixel 5" emulator to a "Medium Phone" emulator was a workaround for me.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue and tried a solution.  It can be fixed by cold booting the emulator.

To do it:

1. Close your emulator.
2. Open Device Manager and click on the down arrow indicating more options.
   [image]
3. Click on Cold boot now.
   [image]
4. Let it start, the increased height issue of the `TopBar` will be fixed.

Comment: it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried looking for an answer, but then I just created a new emulator and deleted the old one. Works great and quick fix

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same situation where in my actual device the status bar height is all normal but in the emulator the status bar height is bigger than expected.

It is definitely a huge bug.

I encountered this bug in following AVD :

- **Pixel 4 API 30/33**

  [image: Screen shot of the bug]

Try to avoid **Pixel 4**, I would suggest you to use **Pixel 3/3a**

I hope folks at Android fix this bug quickly.

Answer (score -6):

Its completely normal. Its just a glith by the emulator because running emulator is a bit for vertualization and HAMX complexity thing to solve. Just Create another instance of OS with different android version like OREO or Nougat. It might solve this error.

Comment: Is there a reset that I can do to solve this? 
Created a new emulator. It worked fine for some days and re-surfaced again.

Comment: It can't be "completely normal", it's a bug, not a glitch because it happens every time. Where can we find a more robust answer than this one ?

Comment: Sad a bug is classified by "completely normal" nowadays. =(

Comment: @Snowirbis If it is, as you say, a bug what more of an answer can you expect? The right course of action would be to make a bug report.

Comment: The main reason why I said its completely normal for the person who asked because  he/she did't gave complete details about what emulator chassis chosen , what os chosen, etc. Because the problem that came is like when u chose an OS with pixel chassis and google play support then that os automatically adds chin to the top bar. Even if in real physical Pixel devices we have bigger chins when the device started shipping with  those cut out displays. Other than that if u choose other OS versions with with chassis other than Pixel and play support Os then the chin will not be there.